# inventory question regarding adding and removing product using dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, inventory-management

I am working on task like this, in a company, they want to sale product called `'computer'`.

- if enough stock does not exists before the sale date, it should give  message for insufficient qty , message.
- Also should give information of total available product quantity for sale before that date, and it's valuation.
- if company have enough quantity for sale, than it should display message of remaining qty of that product and it's valuation.

e.g.

```
valuation = quantity * purchase price
```

my code

```
import datetime

class Supplier:

    def add_supplier(self, name, address, email, contact_no):
       """
        Function: Used to add supplier details.
        Parameter:name: Supplier Name
            address: Supplier address
            email: Supplier email
            contact_no: Supplier Contact detail
        Return: Nothing

        """
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.email = email
        self.contact_no = contact_no

class Product:

    def add_product(self, name):
        """
         Function: To add product in to an inventory.
        Parameter: Product name
        Return: Nothing
        """
        self.name = name

class Company(Supplier, Product):

    data_dict = []

    def purchase(self, product_obj, qty, price, date=datetime.date.today()):
        """
        Function: Used to purchase product.
        Parameter: product_obj: Product object.
                qty: Product quantity.
                price: Product price.
                date: Product date.
        Return:  Nothing
        """
        self.data_dict.append({'product': product_obj.name, 'qty': qty, 'price': price, 'date': str(date)})

    def sale(self, sale_qty, sale_date):
        """
        Function: To sale product from warehouse.
        Parameter:  sale_qty: Product sell quantity.
                    sale_date: Product sell date.
        Return: Nothing
        """
        self.newdict = (sorted(self.data_dict, key=lambda x: x['date']))
        assert sale_qty > 0
        unit_val = 0
        rqilr = 0
        rpilr = 0
        qty = 0
        price = 0
        sum_qty = 0
        sum_price = 0

        #print(newdict) # testing.

         for i, row in enumerate(self.newdict):
            if row['date'] > sale_date:
                print("Sorry, not enough quantity.\nStart the purchase order procedure pls!\n")

            qty += row['qty']
            price += row['price']
            unit_val = price/qty
            # we have enough Computers in stock.
            if qty >= sale_qty:
                break
        else:  # loop completes normally
            for i in self.newdict:
                sum_price += i['price']
                sum_qty += i['qty']

            print("Sorry, not enough qty. Operation cancelled.\nCurrent quantity = {} and valuation = {}".format(sum_qty, sum_price))

        # remaining_qty_in_last_row sort name = rqilr
        rqilr = qty - sale_qty
        rpilr = rqilr * unit_val
        self.newdict = [{**row, 'price': rpilr, 'qty': rqilr}] + self.newdict[i + 1:]
        #print(self.newdict)
        # For current quantity and valuation
        for i in self.newdict:
            sum_price += i['price']
            sum_qty += i['qty']

        print("Sold!\n available quantity = {} and valuation = {}".format(sum_qty, sum_price))


C = Company()
PRODUCT_OBJ = Product()
PRODUCT_OBJ.add_product('Computer')

while True:

    option = int(input("""1. You want to add stock of the product!"
2. Want to sale product?
"""))

    if option == 1:
        qty = int(input("Enter the qty of the product.\n"))
        price = float(input("Enter the price of the product.\n"))
        purchase_date = input("Enter purchase date.\n")
        C.purchase(PRODUCT_OBJ, qty, price, purchase_date)

    elif option == 2:
        qty = int(input("Enter the qty you wanna sale, pal!"))
        sale_date = input("Enter sale date.\n")
        C.sale(qty, sale_date)

    else:
        print("Enter only 1 & 2 option.\n")
```

after executing program I am having menu like in program.

1. You want to add stock of the product!
2. Want to sale product?

but output not getting proper output of remaining `quantity` and `valuation`.

Any suggestion , how to make it right?

Comment: There's too much going on here for me to have time to debug, but I'm suspicious about `Company`s class attribute, `data_dict`. Shouldn't that be an instance attribute?

Comment: can you give a concrete example of input and expected output?

Comment: What is the error you are getting, share your sample inputs, the output you are getting and the expected output

Comment: @Ollie when I choose option 1 and add the quantity in purchase method , and then if I sale qty in sale method, the remaining qty and valuation not getting , something missing in sale method but cant figure it out and how to merge that remaining qty and its valuation in to dictionary which is in purchase method , if you read the task bit carefully you may understand more.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh  when I choose option 1 and add the quantity in purchase method , and then if I sale qty in sale method, the remaining qty and valuation not getting , something missing in sale method but cant figure it out and how to merge that remaining qty and its valuation in to dictionary which is in purchase method , if you read the task bit carefully you may understand more.

Comment: That's why we are asking for a sample run of your code, which shows us the error, and then you can change the sample run to show us what was expected!